# How to show data on qlpreviewcontroller

Tags: ios, cocoa, qlpreviewcontroller

I am using qlpreviewcontroller to show JPG,PNG,PDF and DOCS file. My question is how can I show file preview as in dropbox app? I also want to add navigation bara and toolbar on that. Help Required...

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to use 
self.navigationcontroller.navigationbar.hidden=NO; //For navigationbar

for Toolbar

NSArray* toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
                                                      target:self
                                                      action:@selector(your method name:)],
        [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch 
                                                      target:self
                                                      action:@selector(your method name:)],
        nil];

    self.toolbarItems = toolbarItems;
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
```

Comment: I previewer = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
    [previewer setDataSource:self];
    [self.view addSubview:previewer.view]; I am using

Comment: previewer = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
    [previewer setDataSource:self];
    [self.view addSubview:previewer.view]; on this no touch no gtap gasture is working also I am not able to add toolbar